# Why does my HTACCESS don't work with more than one RewriteRule in PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i've a little problem with multiple RewriteRules in PHP.

This is my htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex start.php

RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule insert          insert_kunde.php
RewriteRule insert2         insert_kunde_2.php
```

If i call *http://127.0.0.1/Adressen-REST/insert* it works fine and redirect me to **insert_kunde.php**.

But if i call *http://127.0.0.1/Adressen-REST/insert2*, i will be redirected to insert_kunde.php, not to insert_kunde_2.php.

If i comment this line out, it works:

```
#RewriteRule insert         insert_kunde.php
```

Does some know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be more precise with your patterns:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?Adressen-REST/insert$ /Adressen-REST/insert_kunde.php [END]
RewriteRule ^/?Adressen-REST/insert2$ /Adressen-REST/insert_kunde_2.php [END]
```

The issue in your example is that the fuzzy pattern `insert` matches all of `/insert`, `/insert2`, `insert_kunde.php` and `insert_kunde_2.php`. So your first rule will *always* get applied. And will get applied again to an already rewritten request.

Comment: ok, but it still doesn't works when I rename the **insert2** to this:

RewriteRule test   insert_kunde_2.php

In this case the pattern wouldn't match...

Comment: I fail to make any sense of that comment, sorry. Of course the pattern won't match any more when you change what is requested. But that is obvious.

Comment: I changed the answer, I initially miised that your resources are not in top level. So I change the rules to use full paths now.

Comment: Ah, now I understand your comment... Sure, if you rewrite from ``test`` to a target `/Adressen-REST/insert_kunde.php` then _cerainly_ the simple pattern ``insert`` will match again. So another rewriting round will get applied. You cannot work with such primitive patterns. I removed that second option.

Comment: Sorry  for the late answer.  I got the solution:
**RewriteRule ^insert1$ insert_kunde.php** 
**RewriteRule ^insert2$ insert_kunde_2.php** 
I got useful informations from this site, how to define mein pattern:
[1]https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708
Thx for the support :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have todo something like this. define internal path too, to tell the server.!

```
RewriteRule insert          insert_kunde.php
RewriteRule insert2         insert_kunde_2.php
```

To this :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /insert_kunde.php\sHTTP  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /insert/ [L,R]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /insert_kunde_2.php\sHTTP  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /insert2/ [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/insert_kunde.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/insert_kunde_2.php [L]
```

i hope this will work.!